# Axios Request to Vimeo Forbidden when Trying to Run from Remote Server

Tags: node.js, axios, http-status-code-403, vimeo

I am using Nodejs server and it is deployed on g-cloud. I make a call to the vimeo API by using axios in my server. When I run the server locally, it runs fine. However, it gives a 403 error when the call is made by the deployed server.

The error seems like this:

```
Error: Request failed with status code 403\n    at createError
(/workspace/node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)\n    at settle
(/workspace/node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:17:12)\n    at
IncomingMessage.
(/workspace/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:312:11)\n    at IncomingMessage.emit
(events.js:326:22)\n    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1241:12)\n    at
processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are getting a `1020 error code`.

> Vimeo/Cloudflare may be blocking requests from google IP's to prevent bot attacks.

[Reference](https://community.cloudflare.com/t/cloudflare-is-blocking-access-from-a-google-cloud-vm/300154)